# Binding in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have created three sliders to quickly input data into Windows Store APP.
Range of each slider is 0-9, all together represents a value from range 000 - 999 in TextBox.

I can calculate the value using following Formula

```
int result = Slider1.Value * 100 + Slider2.Value * 10 + Slider3.Value;
```

I can simply attach this to every slider's ValueChanged Event, but there is a more elegant way Via XAML Binding. I created something like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel() { }

    public double TotalValue { get; set; }
}
```

but I cannot access any of sliders. Is there any way to pass them as constructor parameters? Or any other way to perform this binding?

EDIT
Adding data context

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: Can you show us your XAML? And specify what DataContexts are set and how, if possible

Answer (score 1):

Bind every slider value to a property in the viewmodel:

(make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {

        }

        private double valueSlider1;
        public double ValueSlider1
        {
           get { return valueSlider1; }
           set
           {
              valueSlider1 = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("ValueSlider1");
              RaisePropertyChanged("TotalValue ");
           }
        }
        private double valueSlider2;
        public double ValueSlider2
        {
           get { return valueSlider2; }
           set
           {
              valueSlider2 = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("ValueSlider2");
              RaisePropertyChanged("TotalValue ");
           }
        }
        private double valueSlider3;
        public double ValueSlider3
        {
           get { return valueSlider3; }
           set
           {
              valueSlider3 = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("ValueSlider3");
              RaisePropertyChanged("TotalValue ");
           }
        }
        public double TotalValue
        {
           get { return ValueSlider1*100+ValueSlider2*10+ValueSlider3; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
             var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
             if (handler != null)
             {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
             }
        }
    }
```

Then, apply the binding to the sliders in this way:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: The name 'RaisePropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user2847238 - You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `interface` memebers.

Comment: @user2847238 as I said, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and provide a method that raise the event (`RaisePropertyChanged`)

Comment: @Alberto - Perhaps you could provide `user2847238` with an example of how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your answer?  Might also be of benefit to others too.

Comment: @Veleous I added the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged